# Can i set the canvas window in kivy that i can draw only on the white area and not be able to draw on the other places?

Tags: python, canvas, drawing, kivy, draw

i want to b able to draw only in the white area (the recangle area) for example if your trying to draw behind the buttons or over the label it wont draw. is it possible? i need it for my project in school, i need to be able to draw only in the white area so the paint wont cover the label for example or not to be able drawing under the buttons

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle, Line
from kivy.uix.stencilview import StencilView
from kivy.core.window import Window
import socket
import sys
import os
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from functools import partial



class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    lineSize = 5
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud['Line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y), width=self.lineSize)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['Line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.parent = Widget()
        self.painter=MyPaintWidget(size=(695,510),pos=(100,50))
        with self.painter.canvas:
            Rectangle(pos=(100,50), size=(695,510))
        with open("Send_word.txt",'r') as fr:
            word_lable = Label(text = "Your word is " + fr.read(),font_size='30sp',pos = (400,530))
        self.parent.add_widget(word_lable)

        finishbtn = Button(text='finish',pos=(0, 0),size = (100,150))#finish button position and text
        finishbtn.bind(on_release=self.finish)#finish button onclick

        erasebtn = Button(text = "Erasor",pos=(0,150),size =(100,150))#erasor button position and text
        erasebtn.bind(on_release=self.black)

        redbtn = Button(text = "Red",background_color=(255,0,0,1.0),pos=(100, 0), size=(100,50))
        redbtn.bind(on_release=self.red)

        bluebtn = Button(text = "Blue",background_color=(0,0,255,1.0),pos=(200, 0), size=(100,50))
        bluebtn.bind(on_release=self.blue)

        greenbtn = Button(text = "Green",background_color=(0,255,0,1.0),pos=(300, 0), size=(100,50))
        greenbtn.bind(on_release=self.green)

        whitebtn = Button(text = "Black",pos=(400, 0), size=(100,50))
        whitebtn.bind(on_release=self.white)

        yellowbtn = Button(text = "Yellow",background_color=(255,255,0,1.0),pos=(500, 0), size=(100,50))
        yellowbtn.bind(on_release=self.yellow)

        lightbluebtn = Button(text = "L.Blue",background_color=(0,255,255,1.0),pos=(600, 0), size=(100,50))
        lightbluebtn.bind(on_release=self.lightblue)

        purplebtn = Button(text = "Purple", size=(100,50),background_color=(148,0,211,1.0),pos=(700,0))
        purplebtn.bind(on_release=self.purple)

        sizeupbtn = Button(text = "SizeUp",pos=(0, 300),size = (100,150))
        sizeupbtn.bind(on_release=self.SizeUp)


        sizedowmbtn = Button(text = "SizeDown",pos=(0, 450),size = (100,150))
        sizedowmbtn.bind(on_release=self.SizeDown)



        self.parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        #self.parent.add_widget(word_lable())
        self.parent.add_widget(finishbtn)
        self.parent.add_widget(redbtn)
        self.parent.add_widget(bluebtn)
        self.parent.add_widget(greenbtn)
        self.parent.add_widget(whitebtn)
        self.parent.add_widget(yellowbtn)
        self.parent.add_widget(erasebtn)
        self.parent.add_widget(lightbluebtn)
        self.parent.add_widget(purplebtn)
        self.parent.add_widget(sizeupbtn)
        self.parent.add_widget(sizedowmbtn)
        return self.parent
    def finish(self,obj):
        self.painter.export_to_png("screenshot.png")
        sexi = open("Send_word.txt",'r').read()
        print repr(sexi)
        send_file(sexi)

    def red(self,obj):
        with self.painter.canvas:
            Color(1,0,0)

    def blue(self,obj):
        with self.painter.canvas:
            Color(0,0,1)

    def green(self,obj):
        with self.painter.canvas:
            Color(0,1,0)

    def white(self,obj):
        with self.painter.canvas:
            Color(0,0,0)


    def yellow(self,obj):
        with self.painter.canvas:
            Color(1,1,0)

    def black(self,obj):
        with self.painter.canvas: 
            Color(1,1,1)

    def lightblue(self,obj):
        with self.painter.canvas:
            Color(0,1,1)

    def purple(self,obj):
        with self.painter.canvas:
            Color(1,0,1)

    def SizeUp(self,obj):
        if(self.painter.lineSize <100):
            self.painter.lineSize += 5

    def SizeDown(self,obj):
        if(self.painter.lineSize >1):
            self.painter.lineSize -= 5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that the easy way and the hard way. The easy way is using [`StencilView`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.stencilview.html) as a widget, which has a [nice demo](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/canvas/stencil_canvas.py).

The harder way is using the [`Stencil`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.stencil_instructions.html) directly and target only specific areas of the widget's canvas.

Comment: i treid and tried bt didnt succseed... there is any other way? or can you send me an example for it?

Comment: @YoavLinder Be sure you checked the linked demo.

Comment: i couldnt figure how to do it with this demo... can you show me how to do it inside the code i added to the question please? thanks